# stateListAnimator on Floating Action Button not working

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I set a `stateListAnimator` to Floating Action Button, but it's not working.

Floating Action Button in XML is this:

```
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:tint="@color/sakurairo"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_animation"
            app:layout_behavior=".ui.ScrollAwareFabBehavior"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/wasurenagusairo" />
```

animation XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="10dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="200"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.05" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="200"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1.05" />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="100"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="2dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="200"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.0" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="200"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1.0" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

How `stateListAnimator` in FAB works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Encountered exactly the same problem here. Sadly not found any solutions yet.